# Changing the content of a web page, through JavaScript, by the result of a submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert

I have an HTML form that looks like so:

[image: HTML Form from my site]

The dropdown boxes have options of "Binary", "Decimal", and "Hexadecimal". Based on the values of the dropdown boxes, the value of the "String To Convert" textbox is changed. When the form is submitted, the string inside of the textbox is converted into the base the user has chosen, and then is relayed back to the user in a JavaScript alert.

This is where I encounter my problem:

I'm attempting to change the way the form relays the converted string back to the user. My goal is to have the site overwrite the form with the user's original and converted string. I've attempted to use both a method utilizing InnerHTML, and simply changing the value in the textbox to the converted string. The first of these methods do nothing; the second empties the textbox.

A JSFiddle containing a WORKING version of my code is linked below.

[JSFiddle of my Code](https://jsfiddle.net/decadence18/j6p89ako/3)

Right now I'm returning the string as such:

```
alert("Your binary string " + stringToConvert + " is equal to " + decimalSum + " in decimal!");
```

This is what I would like to change (there are several of these statements in several sections).

The version of the code I linked you all to is a working version, virtually identical to the version on my site. This means any edits I made are not currently in there.

The HTML and JavaScript are separate files.

I would prefer pure JS, but as long as it can be implemented into my current set up it doesn't make a lot of difference. I will accept an answer in any implementation as long as I can get it to work.

Any assistance you all can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using Grisk's answer I was able to come up with a fix for my problem (see the comments of his answer for fix and such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#StringToConvert').val("Your binary string " + stringToConvert + " is equal to " + decimalSum + " in decimal!");
```

will work just fine.  I'm not entirely sure using pure JS, but since you didn't specifically state no jQuery, I'm going to assume you're probably using it.

Comment: Will this work, considering the JavaScript and HTML are different files and the stringToConvert variable does not exist explicitly in the HTML? (This is my mistake; when originally posting the question I forgot to specify that the HTML and JavaScript are separate files.)

Comment: I believe it will, yeah.  The files will be manipulating the same DOM and the variable will still exist as long as it isn't scoped beneath it (aka, if you created it at global scope in the first file, it should still be available in the second file at global scope.)

Also, since your question now specifies pure JS, I believe you can use .text() to set text without jQuery.

Comment: I'm assuming the jQuery would be placed in the HTML... And I'm pretty sure that none of the sums or anything are Global; that may have been what the problem was/is. I'll attempt this fix later (I'm not currently in a situation to edit my files, and I'd also like to see possibly another option) and post back if it works.

Comment: When I say "globally" I really mean "not within any function."  Anything declared just inside a JS file but not within a specific function is implicitly global.

This means that if I have a file a.js which contains just

var a="hello";

and a file b.js:

console.log(a);

as long as b.js is included after a.js, this will actually work.

Comment: I know; I don't think I have any Globally declared variables actually. Most of my variables will be in the lowest-level functions, because they're mostly used one time.

Comment: That's probably better.  In that case, I'd just encase this into a low-level function as well!  write a function that accepts a stringToConvert and you're golden!

Comment: That may work... I'll try a few things based on this answer when I get a chance to.

Comment: Grisk, globally declaring the variable made it work. I was able to successfully replace the content of the document with both jQuery and pure JavaScript (both using innerHTML and replacing the value of the text box). Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help. You may still want to rework it into a conpartmentalized method, just to make it easier to maintain, but I'm glad this worked!